# How to stop renaming of generated files from prod build in angular cli

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I don't want angular cli to rename generated script files by `ng build --prod` and put its link in my index.html file. I just want to use the same name again and again as it does for the development build for the prod build as well.

I know in the `.angular-cli.json` file holds all configuration but what option I need to place to stop renaming of files for prod build.

Other option is as the angular cli is using `webpack` internally, is there any way we can configure `webpack` to handle file renaming.

Comment: Same here ! We need to conserve all initial class names, but angular-cli (throught webpack) rename it. Have you found a good solution for this ? (instead of put  a property into the instance) ?

Comment: This is done on purpose to try and mitigate caching issues... @ChristopheGigax This question is about the file names, not the class names?

Comment: yes, is there an option to stop change class names as well. I would love to do that as we are open sourcing some of our libs

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use `ng build --prod --output-hashing none`

Comment: does disabling the hashing remove the cache-busting ?

Comment: @CruelEngine - yes, setting `--output-hashing none` will create a file like `main.js` as opposed to `main.b35d16684f410b5c0406.js` which will _remove_ cache busting.

Answer (score 0):

In the latest Angular you have to delete the --prod instance, so you can use:

```
ng build --output-hashing none
```